# Обратиться к методу контроллера в представлении

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет!
У меня проблема с доступом к методу контроллера. Мне нужно обратиться к методу из js, используя get. Мой код почему-то не выполняется чуть больше чем полностью.
В чём может быть проблема?

Код:

```
$('#delete_btn').on('click', function () {
        $.get("/List/Delete", { param: 17 }, function (data) {
            $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#delete_btn').on('click', function () {
   $.get("/List/Delete", { param: 17 })
       .success(function(data) {
           $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>'); 
           alert("Успешное выполнение"); })
       .error(function(response) { 
           console.log(response);
           alert("Ошибка выполнения"); })
});
```

Имя параметра в контроллере должно быть `param`, ну либо поменяйте на то, которое в методе, ну и путь должен быть правильным. Если будет ошибка - загляните в консоль, что пишет. Думаю, эта информация вам даст результат для исправления ошибки.

Проблема может быть в том, что имя параметра в ajax-get не соответствует имени в методе контроллера. Также, что путь указан неправильно и вы не туда *стучитесь*, может быть просто написать `$.get("Delete", { param: 17 })...`. Либо у вас просто нет доступа. В `error(function(response)` вы увидите, что у вас не так.